# Displaying report from jFrame by jButton click event

Tags: java, jframe, jasper-reports

I am using NetBeans 8.0.2. I have already created report using *iReport 5.6.0*. After designing I moved it into my existing Java Application project in NetBeans into new folder called **reports**.

My jFrame file **reportform.java** is in same project under **appfolder**. I wish to display/preview my already created report by click of a Button on jFrame **reportform.java**. My report is working/displaying fine otherwise in the same project.

Comment: I am referring Jasper reports (iReport5.6.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            String sfilename="report";
    String path = "appname/" + sfilename + ".jasper";
    String imgp=("images");

    InputStream reportName = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);

    HashMap param = new HashMap();
    param.put("param1","value1");
    param.put("param2","value2");
    param.put("imgpath",imgp); 
    param.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", "appname/"); 

    try {   
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportName, param, conn);

        net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewer jv = new net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewer(jp);

 //Insert viewer to a JFrame to make it showable
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.getContentPane().add(jv);
        jf.validate();
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        jf.setLocation(300,100);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setTitle("JASPER REPORT");
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `JasperReports library`. All tutorials and other references can be found at the Jaspersoft community: [JasperReports library - First Steps](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-tutorial).

When using the report inside a Swing application, this could help:

> If you need to display the report inside a Swing application, you can use the [JRViewer](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/view/JRViewer.html) component that is shipped with the library and consists of an embeddable and configurable javax.swing.JPanel component.